# Is there a set filter option in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with two tables - users and messages.
The two tables have records for multiple companies.
I have to add where `companyNo=$companyNo` to all queries e.g.

```
select * from users where companyNo=$_SESSION['companyNo']
```

and

```
select * from messages where companyNo=$_SESSION['companyNo']
```

Is there a way I can set a 'filter' in MySQL for `companyNo=$_SESSION['companyNo']`
so I can ignore `companyName=$_SESSION['companyNo']` from my SQL queries and
MySQL will automatically return records for `$_SESSION['companyNo']`

Comment: Not in MySQL, it all comes down to your WHERE clause

Comment: @Mark. Oh. Ok. It would have saved me time

Answer (score 0):

You can create [Views](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) in mysql for each value of `$_SESSION['companyNo']` company and query them according to `companyNo=$_SESSION['companyNo']`. It's just a hack, i would not recommend to do this :)